# How many roots does $(x+1)\cos x = x\sin x$ have in $(-2\pi,2\pi)$?

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, nonlinear-system

So the nonlinear equation that I need to find the number of its roots is
$$(x+1)\cos x = x\sin x \qquad \text{with } x\in (-2\pi,2\pi)$$

Using the intermediate value theorem I know that the equation has at least one root on this interval, and if I use drawing I see that $x\sin x$ and $(x+1)\cos x$ intersect in three points, but from drawing I can't know if they might intersect again somewhere.

And the problem is that the number of zeroes is definitely not 3, the options are 4, 5, 6, 7 based on my textbook.
I tried the Fixed point method but $\{x\}$ didn't converge, either my starting point or the function I chose were inappropriate.
Can you help?

Comment: Rewriting as $1+\frac{1}{x}=\tan x$ gives 4 roots in $(-2\pi, 2\pi)$.

Comment: @zkutch, it has $5$ roots. See my answer.

Comment: @SarGe. Thanks, you are right - I missed one in non symmetry. Hope, anyway, my suggestion was helpful.

Comment: @zkutch wow! I really didn't think about changing the equation itself, I kept trying the root finding methods thank you for the hit! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image][image]

From the hint given by @zkutch, it is evident from the graph that the equation has five roots when $x\in[-2\pi,2\pi]$. As suggested by @Claude Leibovici I've posted the original graph which is indeed more nice than the second one. However, students are more familiar with the second one. [Third graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eel09.png) if necessary. `:-)`

Comment: May I suggest you plot the original function (lhs-rhs) ? It is nicer.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, I've done it.

Comment: Thanks for doing it. But plot $lhs-rhs$ It is clearer

Answer (score 3):

**First we can manipulate the expression given:**

$(x+1)\cos x= x\sin x$

**divide both sides by $x\cos x$**

Yielding: $(\frac{x+1}{x})= \tan x $

**The Inverse tangent of both sides yields:**

$\operatorname{arctan}(\frac{x+1}{x})=x$

**We can state without requiring a proof, although can be proved, that:**
$\frac{d}{dz} \operatorname{arctan}(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$

**In our example we could let**
$z=\frac{x+1}{x}$

**So:**
$\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{arctan}(z)= (\frac{d}{dz}\operatorname{arctan}(z)\cdot \frac{dz}{du})$
**By the Chain Rule !**

**Right Hand Side (RHS) of the above expression yields**
$\frac{1}{1+z^2} \cdot \frac{-1}{x^2}$

Substitute value of $z$ in terms of $x$ into the RHS to yield an overall equation:

$\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{arctan}(z)= \frac{1}{1+(\frac{x+1}{x})^2}\cdot\frac{-1}{x^2}$
$= \frac{-1}{x^2+(x+1)^2}$

$ \therefore , \operatorname{arctan}(z)=\int \frac{-1}{x^2+(x+1)^2}$

and as: $\operatorname{arctan}(z)= x$. Then:

$x=\int \frac{-1}{x^2+(x+1)^2}$

**Hopefully you can solve this integral now to find all the solutions for x**

Comment: Excuse me, but if you divide then $x\cos x\neq0$?